# Join tables in Power BI with same result like mapping attributes in Micro Strategy

Tags: powerbi, microstrategy

I would like use Power BI for visualization and will not use Micro Strategy anymore. I mapped (joined) two tables by 3 attributes.
It means table1 has for example attributes:
Name
Cost
State
Year
Color
Price

table2 has:
Name
Cost
State
Month
Material
Amount

I mapped attributes Name - Name, Cost - Cost, State - State. We can say, that it is not Primary Key. Later, when I create some math function, for example Unit = Price / Amount is possible to do it.
In Power BI we can´t join tables by this way. My question is, how can I join these tables in Power BI with same results like in Micro Strategy? What should I do? You can join tables in Power BI only by one attribute (Primary Key). Or you can use for example Outer Join connection, but I don´t have same results.

Than you very much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI, you can only join by a single key, so when you have multiple keys you want to join by, you normally create an intermediate table, which has a pseudo key and then use that pseudo key to join to three tables.

For Example,
Table1
NewKey
Year
Price

Table2
NewKey
Month
Material
Amount

NewTable
NewKey
Name
Cost
State